# Can I store TIM->CNT to an int variable to keep track of elapsed time?

Tags: c, stm32

Say I have a 16Mhz Nucleo-F4 clock frequency and I want to vary the brightness of an LED pin by controlling the Duty Cycle of the current across the LED, while at the same time blinking the LED at 500ms. However, with my prescaler and auto-reset register configurations, I can only count up until 8ms for every cycle.

`TIM-> PSC = 99; //effective frequency is 160kHz, 1 count = 6.25us TIM -> ARR = 1279; // one cycle = 8ms`

Can I create an int variable where I can store CNT value so that I can keep track of how much time has elapsed?

`int total_CNT; ... total_CNT += TIM -> CNT`

Example implementation:

```
while (1){
   total_CNT += TIM -> CNT;
   if (total_CNT % 160000 < 800001){ //160000*6.25us = 1s & 80000*6.25us = 0.5s
       //do something for the first half of a second
   }
   else {
       //do something during the 2nd half of a second
   }
}
```

Please note that the ARR and PSC values are being used to vary the brightness of the load by PWM (blinking the light at a very fast speed to make it appear ON all the time and varying the duty cycle to "reduce or increase the brightness")

PS: I have tried implementing this on an actual code but the LED is not blinking as desired.

Comment: Yes, but you cannot just accumulate CNT like that in a loop. Imagine CNT goes from 300 to 301 on subsequent loops. You will have added up to 601 when in reality only 1 timer clock period has elapsed. One solution might be to count the ARR periods (use the timer update event or interrupt) and if you need to have timer resolution less than 1 ARR period then you could add CNT to that (but not accumulate). If you can modify your timing so that the 8ms becomes a whole divisor of the 500ms then you only need to count ARR periods and do not need to use CNT.

Comment: Your MCU probably has many other timers, and a sysTick timer. You'd be as well to use one of those for the LED.

Comment: oh I see. I figure I can use other MCU timers. Thanks a lot!

Comment: “Current” goes thru; “Voltage” goes across. :)